# Find where dll is loaded from in C++ program (MFC)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc

I have large legacy C++ application (Visual Studio 2010), and I need to execute some code before a specific dll is loaded. The problem is the dll is getting loaded before I execute any code, so I'm trying to figure out what's triggering it to load.

I've specified /DELAYLOAD for the dll in the link options, which should stop the dll loading before it's needed. But it's still getting loaded before I execute any code. The application is MFC, so my entry point is an override of CWinApp::InitApplication().

I suspect it must be a global variable in the application that's referencing a type in the dll, but I'm not sure how to find the variable (the code base is large, and globals are not consistently named).

Any ideas how to find what's triggering the dll load, or how to find the global variable?

Comment: Look for `LoadLibrary` calls, or if implicitly loaded `#pragma comment (lib...)` lines.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: The OP is looking for DLLs that are loaded before any user code runs. `CWinApp::InitApplication` is the moral equivalent of C's `main`. The OP isn't looking for explicit `LoadLibrary` calls, nor are they looking for linker directives (they already know, that the library is linked in). They are looking for the reason, why a delay-load library loads, although seemingly no export is touched yet.

Comment: You could override the delay-load *helper function*, and check what symbol(s) trigger the DLL to load. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09t6x5ds(v=vs.100).aspx.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, this got it. Actually I had trouble getting over-riding the delay-loader correctly, but found you can just put a breakpoint in the default one... __delayLoadHelper2() in delayhlp.cpp. I did this, and it identified a global singleton whose initialiser referenced a type in the dll. If you want to put it as a full response I'll accept it.

Comment: Good that it worked out. Mine was only a hint, and in fact I like yours better as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the problem by setting a breakpoint on the [delay-load helper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09t6x5ds.aspx) function, `__delayLoadHelper2`. This function can be found in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\delayhlp.cpp
```

It's called when a dll marked for delay-load is loaded.

I set the breakpoint in `__delayLoadHelper2` and viewed the call-stack when it was hit. This showed the function in my code that was triggering the dll-load.

It was triggered by a global singleton constructor, which created a type from the dll. This code gets executed before `CWinApp::InitApplication()`.

Comment: I don't understand, how the debugger maps the object code to the source (delayhlp.cpp). I couldn't find a matching .pdb file that ships with Visual Studio. Do you happen to know, how (and why) this works?

Comment: @IInspectable Delayhlp.cpp is compiled with (quoting from the source file) `Build instructions: cl -c -O1 -Z7 -Zl -W3 delayhlp.cpp`. The `/Z7` means that the debug information is included in the object file, and in turn into the delayimp.lib the program links in. From [Debug Information Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx): `To create a library that contains debugging information without using .pdb files, you must select the compiler's C 7.0-Compatible (/Z7) option`.

Comment: @dxiv: Perfect! Being ubiquitously common with Microsoft's compiler to separate debug information and object code, it didn't even occur to me, that you could embed debug information in the final executable module. Doing this for the delayimp.lib is a great application, enabling debugging of delay-loading out-of-the-box. Sometimes I'm impressed by the attention to details, that really makes up for all those other times, when I'm not...

Comment: This worked for me, though I had to put the dll it was trying to load in the same directory. If the dll is not found it never seems to get to this function.